# Corrupted files ? visualising pictures

Tags: qfield, atlas, qfield-cloud, picture

I have an issue to resolve with QGIS.

I collected data during field visits using QField, including photos. As I collected them, these data were uploaded to a QField Cloud account without any issue.

After the collection phase, in QGIS, I Created a layout and inserted these photos, which initially posed no problem to be visualized when generating an atlas.
Made a mistake by reducing the size of the photo files in the DCIM folder on my disk because the capacity limit of my QField account was going to be reached.
Synchronized, which resulted in duplicating the photos on the cloud: QField Cloud keeps previous versions of files in the history to be able to recover them (similar to any cloud service).
Now, in the layout on QGIS, there are red crosses appearing instead of the photos when I generate the atlas and want to visualize the result. QGIS must be interpreting that these files are corrupted, I imagine; but when I open the form of an entity, it has no problem generating a visualization of the photos. So, the file names and access fields are functional.

I have tried, in vain:

- To "clean up" the files on the cloud to keep only one version of each file,
- Creating a new layout with new "photo" objects,
- Replacing the photo files in the DCIM directory with the original photos that I had archived just in case.

Would you know how to solve this problem?